# Using PHP or jQuery to submit a dynamically generated file

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, forums

I am trying to interact with the "API" at another company. Their API is actually a file upload form which asks for a CSV file. It's a standard HTML form with an element like so:

```
<input type="file" id="inputFileUploadFile" name="UploadFile">
```

I have a page where a user can view a set of table data.  I am looking for a way to have a one-button solution where the user can look at the table data and *submit it as a file* to this so-called API.

Generating the data in CSV format is easy enough. The question, specifically, is how do I then get that data into the form element and submit it?

I can either use jQuery to manipulate and submit a hidden HTML form, or I can use PHP to submit the form directly. An answer in either format works.

Comment: hello :- with jquery you can use FormData  class object and assgin the file to it and then send this data to server .if this approach is fine for you I can come up with some answer .

Comment: please try if any issues please let me know I am hpy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use FormData Class . Below find below a sample code . You need to call this inside the function when you are calling the post on button click etc.

```
        --- add  enctype to form tag----  
       <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        -- on submit create a new object assing key value pairs and post it .

        var formData = new FormData($('#upload_form')[0]);

        formData.append('key1', 'val1');
        formData.append('key2', 'val2');
        // Main magic with files here
        formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 


        $.ajax({
            url: 'Your url here',
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            // THIS MUST BE DONE FOR FILE UPLOADING
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            // ... Other options like success and etc
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yashveer Singh, I was able to put all the pieces together. Here's the jQuery/javascript version:

```
//first, create a Blob object. Assume that variable myCSV has our CSV data as a string
//The Blob constructor requires an array, so place in brackets [].
var myblob = new Blob([myCSV], {type: 'text/csv'});

//Create a new FormData object.
var myFD = new FormData();
//Add our file (the blob) to it.
myFD.append('htmlFormName', myblob, 'someFileName.csv');
//We can also append other fields if necessary.
myFD.append('inputName', 'inputValue');

//If we're using jQuery to send the form...
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://remotewebsite.com/formhandler.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: myFD,
    processData: false, // <-- important!
    contentType: false, // <-- important!
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Posted successfully.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Great :) Happy coding :)